# How can i get the male female percentage in MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server

This is how my table looks like,Here is 1 is male and 2 is female

```
Id  Gender
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     1
```

this is how i expected the answer

[image: percentage]

code that i tried

```
Select 
 Pt.Id,
 Pt.Gender,
 sum(case when Gender= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as maleCount,
 sum(case when Gender= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as femalecount

 from Patients Pt
 WHERE Pt.Isactive = 1 and Pt.IsDeleted=0  
 Group by Pt.Id,Pt.Gender
```

I want to get the male and female percentage.How can i achieve it

Comment: You're grouping by the `Id` of the patient here, is that intended? You'll only get one row per patient then, and I suspect that your patients *don't* have multiple genders

Comment: As for getting a percentage, a conditional `AVG` is one method.

Comment: No it doesn't can you suggest any answer from the above question

Comment: Looks to answer the question to me, @MikeMicky . Can you *explain* why it doesn't?

Comment: i couldn't understand exactly. Can you give me the exact answer to my question

Comment: Then explain what you don't understand. Explain why the answers don't answer your question, (when they most certainly do). Demonstrate your attempt(s) to implement the solutions, and what about them aren't working.